# How to refresh component on page after a change on the screen

Tags: c#, events, action, tabcontrol

I have a form which contains a tab control.  One tab has one user control, another has a different user control.  The first tab has a bunch of check boxes.  Based on the selection of the checkboxes, a combobox on the other tab is populated with different data.  The problem is, the user controls are both loaded when the form is loaded, so the data for the combo box is already set.  I want to reload the data in the combobox when the selection on the other tab changes.  I'm not sure how to accomplish this because I can't directly call a method in one user control from the other.  A coworker suggested I look into event Actions.  Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Enter event on the tabs and put the refresh code in there. This solution is not perfect because the pages won't refresh until you "enter" them through the TabControl.

Another other option would be to keep a reference to the TabControl inside each page and upon data update, refresh the pages listening to this data.

Answer (score 0):

"I can't directly call a method in one user control from the other."

True...but the Form can act as the "middle man".  The first UserControl can raise a custom event that the second UserControl subscribes to.  You can manually wire it up in the Forms Load() event since the Form has a reference to both UserControls.